# Save the matches of grep as an array

Tags: grep

I have a file with the following contents:

```
FILETYPE=A:B:C:D
```

How can I `grep` out `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` and save them as an array in a ksh script on Linux? I tried

```
FILETYPES=`grep "FILETYPE" ${CONF_FILE} | awk -F: '{print $NF}'`
```

But that only gets the last one.

Comment: im using shel ksh

Comment: What OS are you using? Is it Linux or something else?

Comment: Linux, ksh script.

Answer (score 5):

On GNU/Linux and with ksh93 or mksh (or `zsh`'s ksh emulation mode), you can do:

```
set -o noglob
filetypes=( $(grep -Po 'FILETYPE=\K.*' < "$CONF_FILE" | tr ':' ' ') )
```

(assuming the default value of `$IFS`)

Or, more idiomatically:

```
set -o noglob
IFS=:
filetypes=( $(grep -Po 'FILETYPE=\K.*' < "$CONF_FILE"))
```

Note that I used lower case letters for the array name, that's usually safer since environmental variables are usually capitalized. The way to save the output of a command as an array is:

```
array=( $(command) )
```

After having disabled glob and set the field separator.

Then, the command itself is `grep` (here assuming GNU `grep` or compatible with Perl Compatible Regular Expressions support enabled (`-P`)), these give us `\K` which means *"discard anything matched up to this point"*. The `-o` causes `grep` to only print the matched portion of the line and, combined with the `\K`, makes it only print `A:B:C:D` here. Finally, the `tr` replaces the `:` with spaces which happens to be in the default value of `$IFS`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${filetypes[0]}"
A
$ printf '%s\n' "${filetypes[3]}" 
D
```

Comment: I failed to save it as array. Is it ok to give a direct answer?

Comment: @user548682 I don't understand. If you want to post your own answer, yes, it is perfectly OK. I don't see why this would have failed though.

Comment: GPGDIRLISTS=( `( $(grep -Po 'GPGDIRLIST=\K.*' ${CONF_FILE} | tr ':' ' ') )` )

Comment: Wonder why it failed.I used for loop like this, but it couldnt treat it as array. It still list out all items inside.

for GPGDIRLIST in $GPGDIRLISTS

Comment: @user548682 because you added an extra set of parentheses. Try `GPGDIRLISTS=( $(grep -Po 'GPGDIRLIST=\K.*' ${CONF_FILE} | tr ':' ' ') )`.

Comment: When I echo $GPGDIRLISTS, it lists the 1st item twice.
A
A

Comment: Could also use a single awk `awk 'sub(/FILETYPE=/,"")&&gsub(/:/," ")'`

Comment: @user548682 yes, that only prints the first element of the array. To show the whole array use `echo ${GPGDIRLIST[@]}`

Comment: @123 oh there are hundreds of ways to do this. I just thought it safer not to introduce another scripting language to the OP. Personally, I'd have just done `awk -F[=:] '/FILETYPE/{print $2,$3,$4,$5}' file`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. 
Now, Im trying to call it one by one.
Is this for loop correct? BTW, I got A:B for the for loop.
for GPGDIRLIST in ${GPGDIRLISTS[@]}

Comment: Yes, that should work. I have no idea what you mean by "I got A:B for the loop". If you have a new question, please ask it in a new post.

Comment: Hi Terdon, due to some issue, infra team has reverted back to Kernel 5.9. And now my script doesnt work. This command is not working. 
TESTERS=( $(grep -Po 'TESTER=\K.*' ${CONF_FILE} | tr ':' ' ') )
Could you please advise? Thanks.

Comment: @user548682 the kernel shouldn't affect this. And kernel 5.9 doesn't exist yet. As I said before though, if you have a new question, please post it separately. Link back to this one, show your input data and what happens when you run this command.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

```
array=( `grep -Po '(?<=FILETYPE=).*$' $CONFIG_FILE | tr ':' ' '` )
```

Explanation: grep uses a "look behind" assertion to return whatever follows "FILETYPE=".

It'll end up declaring the array as:

```
array=(A B C D)
```

Then test:

```
echo "${array[0]} ${array[1]} ${array[2]} ${array[3]}"
```

Prints:

```
A B C D
```

Answer (score 0):

With `ksh93` or `mksh`:

```
{ read -rd=; IFS=: read -rA filetypes; } <file
```

The command within `{...;}` above would first read up to and including the first `=` character in the input.  This part of the input would be stored in the `REPLY` variable and is not later used for anything. The code then proceeds from there and reads the `:`-delimited strings into the array `filetypes`.

The `-d` option to `read` in `ksh` makes the command read up to the given character (rather than up to a newline character). The `-A` option to the command makes it read into an indexed array rather than into a string variable.  When using `-A`, the value of the `IFS` variable is used to split up the array elements in the input.

Testing:

```
$ cat file
FILETYPE=A:B:C:D
```

```
$ { read -rd=; IFS=: read -rA filetypes; } <file
```

```
$ printf '"%s"\n' "${filetypes[@]}"
"A"
"B"
"C"
"D"
```

Changing `-A` to `-a` would make the code work in `bash`.

---

If the file contains other lines that you may not want to read, then with `ksh93`, use

```
grep '^FILETYPE=' file | { read -rd=; IFS=: read -rA filetypes; }
```

Note that this does not work in `mksh` nor `bash` unless the `lastpipe` shell option is set and the code runs in a non-interactive shell (i.e. a script) with job-control disabled (and with `-A` changed to `-a` as mentioned above).